# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi buscador me muestre los resultados en otra página diferente a la que él está?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Tengo un buscador en mi página principal pero quiero que al momento que presione `Enter` este me muestre los resultados de la búsqueda en otro `html`.

¿Cómo podría hacer eso?

Aclaro estoy utilizando `php` y `ajax`. Igual me serviría para los demás buscadores que están en las otras páginas que cuando yo realizo una búsqueda siempre me mande los resultados a mi página `resultados.html`.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta es muy amplia y necesita detalles para poder ayudarte. ¿Cómo haces la búsqueda? Ya sabemos que con Ajax y del lado back usas PHP, pero sin ver el código actual es imposible decirte una respuesta. Pudes leer [mcve]. Tal vez lo que buscas es enviar una [cabecera](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php) de redirección. Saludos

Comment: Si estás usando AJAX no tiene sentido abrir los resultados en otra página (ni recargar la actual). Puedes usar [`target="_blank"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/form#attr-target)

Comment: Nos podrías mostrar el código de la búsqueda Yeisson?

Answer (score 0):

### Diseño

Por lo que escribes INFIERO que tienes el siguiente modelo...

[image: Modelo sugerido]

Dentro de tu HTML es probable que tengas un <form> con un <input> donde el usuario ingresa los datos para la busqueda

### Solución

El tag <form> te permite agregar el parámetro target con valor blank para que la pagina actual no se redireccione y lo abrirá en una nueva tab.

```
<form target="_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename"\>
```

Para usar esta opción no necesitas utilizar AJAX, utiliza el comportamiento por defecto del form con el parámetro action. Modifica el servicio para que imprima de forma amigable al usuario.

[image: NewModel]